# cv2.cvtcolor bgr2gray seems get an error image

Tags: python, opencv, bgr

# the code is as follows, implemented, but the result is possibly wrong, it is not the grayscale i wanted, someone gonna help me with that, it's seems quite simple, but i just don't know what wrong

import cv2
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    img = cv2.imread('calibration_test.png')

```
# i want simply convert the rgb image to grayscale and then print it out
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)
print(gray.shape)
# but the outcome is a colorful image
```

[image: the original image i used]

[image: the ugly outcome]

Answer (score 9):

The grayscale conversion was done correctly. The problem is in how you are displaying the image. Try this:

```
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
```

By default `imshow` adds it's own colour key to single channel images, to make it easier to view. A typical example is thermal images which usually show blue and red, but all the colours are only dependend on *one* channel.

Hope this helps!